# Ubuntu 17.10 issue with F10 shortcut

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys, 17.10

I did a fresh install of 17.10 and have an issue with the <kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut. I need the <kbd>F10</kbd> to close Midnight Commander in terminal. In Unity I knew how to disable the shortcut, but in gnome this seems not to work at all. I did tried:

```
Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts
```

and disabled anything containing F10 with no luck. In terminal I disabled the shortcuts as well. Also some old solutions like this:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
@binding-set NoKeyboardNavigation {
unbind "<shift>F10"
}

* {
gtk-key-bindings: NoKeyboardNavigation
}
```

seems not to work.

Any help will be appreciated, thks.

Comment: I assume you're talking about `gnome-terminal`. Have you turned off its Prefereces -> "Enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default)"?

Comment: No I did not, please post this as an answer. This was it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can disable the handling of <kbd>F10</kbd> in `GNOME Terminal`'s Preferences dialog, General tab.

While at it, you might also want to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> mnemonics here, as well as <kbd>F1</kbd> (and if required, <kbd>F11</kbd> too) under the Shortcuts tab.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I did not see that with the menu accelerator :)

Answer (score 6):

To disable F10 to access Terminal menu:

1) `sudo apt install dconf-tools`

2) run dconf-editor > browse to `org/gnome/terminal/legacy`

3) turn off `menu-acceletator-enabled` (Custom Value -> false)

4) close the terminal, open it again

Thanks firepol for your suggestion.

Comment: Or rewritten in a way for people to follow it 1:1 (& copy paste the commands)
1) `sudo apt install dconf-tools`
2) run `dconf-editor` > browse to `org/gnome/terminal/legacy`
3) turn off `menu-acceletator-enabled`
4) close the terminal, open it again. F10 is now free again. Enjoy. I upvoted your answer anyway, since I could finally get rid of that annoyng shortcut and be able to close midnight commander via F10 again. Thx for that.

Comment: it works ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

Though I feel [egmont's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967567/509312) is the best solution, maybe this additional option may be useful to someone.

If you don't want to:

- perform any mouse clicks
- disable `F10` opening menu (for some reason)

You can also (as [DarkDust](https://superuser.com/a/199892/682230) points out) emulate `F10` key press by pressing: `ESC` followed by `0`

Comment: Good to know this, thks.

Answer (score 2):

You need not disable <kbd>F10</kbd>. You can simply click (with the mouse) on the <kbd>Quit</kbd> 'button' in the bottom right corner to quit from Midnight Commander.

[image]